# Inpainting depth map, still a black image border

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to inpaint missing depth values of a depth map using the method described [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/03/05/neat-opencv-smoothing-trick-when-kineacking-kinect-hacking-w-code/). To summarize the method:

1. Downsize depth map to 20% of the original size
2. Inpaint all black (unknown) pixels in the downsized image
3. Upsize to original size
4. Replace all black pixels in the original image with corresponding values from the upsized image

Super simple and everything works well. A video showing the results can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0A4OVZxzKQ).

However, I wonder why the left and top image border are still black although they should be inpainted (can be seen in the video). My first thought was that this could have to do something with the border interpolation (black pixels outside the image boundary), but than I would expect this also to happen on the other image borders. My second thought was that it is something specific to the used inpainting method (method by Alexandru Telea), but changing it to the Navier-Stokes based method didn't change the results.

Can somebody explain to me why this happens and how to tell OpenCV to also inpaint these regions, if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably the values on the left side aren't 255? can you add another window that shows all depth values which equal 255 in depthf? e.g. `cv::imshow("newWindowName", depthf == 255);` If that's the reason you could change the used mask to `> 250` or something instead of `== 255` in line 13 and 16 of the linked code.

Comment: Since I get unknown depth values as 0, for me it would be depthf == 0 or depthf > 5, but anyway, here are some images: [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qt8lafqDaeQy03QndSMkUxUkU/edit?usp=sharing) shows an example depth map. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qt8lafqDaeZUNOdVBNMlNLcXc/edit?usp=sharing) is the mask that is used for inpainting. And [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qt8lafqDaeSi01cmJDc3Byc1U/edit?usp=sharing) is the result. Any ideas @Micka? The left border is somehow strange, but lets stick to the top border. It is clearly included in the mask.

Comment: Did you have a look at _tmp1 and _tmp?

Comment: did you finally solve this problem? because at the moment I am facing exactly the same issue. @Micka what do you mean by looking at _tmp1 and _tmp? Thanks.

Comment: @theodore unfortunately the images provided by thomas in the comment aren't available anymore, so I can just guess (it's from 2014). In the provided link, the variables _tmp and _tmp1 are used. Maybe I wanted him to have a closer look to the values in there.

Comment: @Micka well if you think that is ok I can open a new thread. On the other hand I have created a thread at the official Opencv forum. You can check it here http://answers.opencv.org/question/86569/inpainting-depth-map-still-black-image-borders/?comment=86587#comment-86587 (you will also find some images). The result is replicated all the time, so I do not know if this is a normal behavior or a possible bug. What do you think.

Comment: @theodore did you try to use the inpainting without resizing first? Maybe resizing removed some of the black parts completely because of interpolation etc. If that's the case, you'll need some custom resizing that will choose the minimum value of the area instead of interpolating. Interpolation is in fact ok, so atm no idea. I'll try the code soon with your input image =)

Comment: @theodore looks like impaint doesn't handle the image border correctly. You can create a border manually with `cv::copyMakeBorder` to fix that. Should I write an answer?

Answer (score 5):

After asked by @theodore in http://answers.opencv.org/question/86569/inpainting-depth-map-still-black-image-borders/?comment=86587#comment-86587 I've used the sample images to test the inpaint behavious. It looks like it does not handle the border correctly, so creating a border with `cv::copyMakeBorder` can be used.

Here's the extended version with some kind of unit testing:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/depthInpaint.png");
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::cvtColor(input, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat inpainted;
    const unsigned char noDepth = 0; // change to 255, if values no depth uses max value or use the mask image
    //cv::inpaint(img, (img == noDepth), depth, 5.0, cv::INPAINT_TELEA); // img is the 8-bit input image (depth map with blank spots)


    double inpaintRadius = 5;
    int makeBorder = 1;
    cv::Mat borderimg;
    cv::copyMakeBorder(img, borderimg, makeBorder, makeBorder, makeBorder, makeBorder, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
    cv::imshow("border", borderimg);
    cv::inpaint(borderimg, (borderimg == noDepth), inpainted, inpaintRadius, cv::INPAINT_TELEA); // img is the 8-bit input image (depth map with blank spots)

    cv::Mat originalEmbedded = borderimg(cv::Rect(makeBorder, makeBorder, img.cols, img.rows));
    cv::Mat inpaintedEmbedded = inpainted(cv::Rect(makeBorder, makeBorder, img.cols, img.rows));


    cv::Mat diffImage;
    cv::absdiff(img, originalEmbedded, diffImage);
    cv::imshow("embedding correct?", diffImage > 0);

    cv::Mat mask = img == noDepth;
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);


    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("inpainted", inpainted);
    cv::imshow("inpainted from border", inpaintedEmbedded);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the reduced version if you believe it to be correct:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/depthInpaint.png");
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::cvtColor(input, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat inpainted;
    const unsigned char noDepth = 0; // change to 255, if values no depth uses max value or use the mask image
    //cv::inpaint(img, (img == noDepth), depth, 5.0, cv::INPAINT_TELEA); // img is the 8-bit input image (depth map with blank spots)

    double inpaintRadius = 5;
    int makeBorderSize = 1;
    cv::Mat borderimg;
    //cv::copyMakeBorder(img, borderimg, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
    cv::copyMakeBorder(img, borderimg, makeBorderSize, makeBorderSize, makeBorderSize, makeBorderSize, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
    //cv::imshow("border", borderimg);
    cv::inpaint(borderimg, (borderimg == noDepth), inpainted, inpaintRadius, cv::INPAINT_TELEA); // img is the 8-bit input image (depth map with blank spots)

    // extract the original area without border:
    cv::Mat inpaintedEmbedded = inpainted(cv::Rect(makeBorderSize, makeBorderSize, img.cols, img.rows));



    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("inpainted from border", inpaintedEmbedded);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's Input:

[image]

Here's the input with border (bordersize 5 to visualize the effect better):

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: many thanks for the answer ;-). Unfortunately, I cannot mark it as a solution since only the thread starter can but you got my upvote. Many thanks again.

Comment: yes I know, thx. It isn't a direct solution to the thread starters question, since he didn't post his code, but probably the same mechanics would help him too. Have fun and please answer or update your question on OpenCV website with the solution.

Comment: yup I will, I think I will also open an issue at github ;-)